# Does while loop check every condition?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

Let's say I have the following loop in C: while(x1 && x2).
If the first condition is false (x1==0) then will the while loop check the second condition?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `while` (there's only one condition) and everything to do with `&&`.

Comment: This is fundamental and it's covered in any basic C textbook. And, as @melpomene pointed out, it has nothing to do with `while`. I recommend you learn the language properly by reading such a book instead of asking piecemeal questions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the first condition is false (x1==0) then will the while loop check the second condition?

No. It won't.

It's called [*short circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

From [C11, 6.5.13](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.13p4):

> Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
>   a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
>   operands. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand
>   is not evaluated.

---

Similarly in `cond1 || cond2`, if `cond1` evaluates to *true* then `cond2` won't be evaluated. See: [C11, 6.5.14](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.14):

> Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
>   a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
>   operands. If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

If the first condition evaluates to false, the second condition is guaranteed by the standard *not* to be evaluated.

From section 6.5.13 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *4* Unlike the bitwise binary `&` operator, the `&&` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if  the  second  operand  is 
>   evaluated,  there  is  a  sequence  point  between  the  evaluations 
>   of the  first  and  second  operands.   **If  the  first  operand 
>   compares  equal  to  0,  the  second operand is not evaluated.**

Answer (score 0):

No, if the first condition is false it will directly stop there.
That way you can avoids errors like segmentation faults if you want to check things such as `if (arrayLength < 10 && array[15] == 'c')` assuming arrayLength is the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

C performs short-circuit evaluation. If `x1` is false, there's no way the entire expression could be true, so `x2` is never evaluated.